# Bootstrap image size thumbnail - I want responsive squares without frames

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I need help :(
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Bootstrap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cs">


<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/175/male-user-icon-vector-illustration_175552829.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
```

I would like to place icons on the website but I don't want any frames. On my picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAPW4.jpg I wrote what I meant. 
Pls guys help 
I would like to place icons on the website but I don't want any frames. On my picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAPW4.jpg I wrote what I meant. 
Pls guys help

Comment: Did you try `.thumbnail {border: 0;}` ?

Comment: Oooh man, I just figured it out!

.thumbnail {
   border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

Comment: I think you mean responsive, not responsible

Answer (score 0):

Use the below css to get it.
In your **bootstrap css** the border style is fixed to **border: 1px solid #ddd;**. That why there is borders.

```
.thumbnail {

 border: 0px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, I used:

```
.thumbnail {
border: 0 none;
box-shadow: none;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The answer was background-color (transparency!) and border :)
Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove the border and shadow from .thumbnail.

```
.thumbnail{
border:none;
box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this to your style :

```
.thumbnail{
    border: none;
}
```

You can go through this :

> [https://jsfiddle.net/azw9pdmv/](https://jsfiddle.net/azw9pdmv/5/)

you can modifying it to suit for your style.